# SQL Server - Get the Latest Date With Grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am running a problem with SQL Server query that I couldn't figure out how to get it works correctly. I try to get the MAX date based on the Category grouped. I know it sounds confused, so let me explain what the result I want.

Let's say I have this table:

```
Table1
Category    Value   UpdatedDateTime
Cat1        5       2017-11-12 10:46
Cat1        2       2017-11-13 11:46    
Cat1        4       2017-11-13 10:46    
Cat2        5       2017-11-12 10:46    
Cat2        7       2017-11-12 11:46    
Cat2        3       2017-11-13 09:46    
Cat3        1       2017-11-12 10:46    
Cat3        2       2017-11-12 11:46    
Cat3        7       2017-11-13 11:46    
Cat3        8       2017-11-13 10:46    
Cat3        3       2017-11-10 10:46    
Cat4        4       2017-11-13 10:46    
Cat4        4       2017-11-12 10:46
```

I want the UpdatedDateTime in the result to pick the latest date by the Category grouping like this:

```
Category    Value   UpdatedDateTime
Cat1        5       2017-11-13 11:46
Cat1        2       2017-11-13 11:46    
Cat1        4       2017-11-13 11:46    
Cat2        5       2017-11-13 09:46    
Cat2        7       2017-11-13 09:46    
Cat2        3       2017-11-13 09:46
Cat3        1       2017-11-13 11:46    
Cat3        2       2017-11-13 11:46    
Cat3        7       2017-11-13 11:46    
Cat3        8       2017-11-13 11:46    
Cat3        3       2017-11-13 11:46    
Cat4        4       2017-11-13 10:46    
Cat4        4       2017-11-13 10:46
```

I tried this query, but of course it doesn't work because I was looking for the Max(UpdatedDate) for the entire table, not by Category.  Then I got stuck.

```
With cte AS 
(
    Select Category, Value, UpdatedDateTime FROM Table1
)
Select Category, Sum(Value)
, (Select Top 1 Max(UpdatedDateTime) FORM cte) AS UpdatedDateTime
FROM cte
Group By Category
```

Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `CTE`? Since you are doing the `SUM(Value)`, just put in the column for `MAX(UpdatedDateTime)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do can this with a partitioned window function easily.

```
declare @Something table
(
    Category varchar(10)
    , MyValue int
    , UpdatedDateTime datetime
)

insert @Something values
('Cat1', 5, '2017-11-12 10:46')
, ('Cat1', 2, '2017-11-13 11:46')    
, ('Cat1', 4, '2017-11-13 10:46')    
, ('Cat2', 5, '2017-11-12 10:46')    
, ('Cat2', 7, '2017-11-12 11:46')    
, ('Cat2', 3, '2017-11-13 09:46')    
, ('Cat3', 1, '2017-11-12 10:46')    
, ('Cat3', 2, '2017-11-12 11:46')    
, ('Cat3', 7, '2017-11-13 11:46')    
, ('Cat3', 8, '2017-11-13 10:46')    
, ('Cat3', 3, '2017-11-10 10:46')    
, ('Cat4', 4, '2017-11-13 10:46')    
, ('Cat4', 4, '2017-11-12 10:46') 

select Category
    , MyValue
    , UpdatedDateTime  = MAX(UpdatedDateTime) over(partition by Category)
from @Something
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.Category, t1.Value, t2.maxDate AS UpdatedDateTime 
FROM Table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN (Select Category, Max(UpdatedDateTime) AS maxDate FROM Table1 Group By Category)
t2 ON t2.Category = t1.Category
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you always get the latest row in each Category

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() 
       OVER (PARTITION BY Category ORDER BY UpdatedDateTime DESC) AS RowNum,
    * FROM Table1) AS Table2 WHERE RowNum = 1
```

Comment: I tried and noticed how your solution gets the latest row.  However, this is not working for me when I have Sum and Group By since it only filter those records with RowNum = 1.  Thanks away for trying to help.